# How do i set a Bean property value from JTextField in Java?

Tags: java, xml, spring, swing

I have a JTextField in a LogInWindow(JFrame). In that JTextField the user enters it's name.

I have another StudentWindow (JFrame) and its constructor has that user name String as a parameter.

In my xml file how can i inject the input from the JTextField ?

```
<!-- GUI Beans -->
<bean id="logInWindow" class="gui.LogInWindow">
    <constructor-arg ref="controller"/>
    <property name="nameJTextField" value="?? Need help here ??"/>
</bean>

<bean id="studentWindow" class="gui.StudentWindow">
<constructor-arg ref="????????"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Spring parses the XML and creates beans based on it before either of your `JFrame` is ever showing. Unless I completely misunderstand your case...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Ive just started learning Spring. I probably should research a little more.

Comment: Probably...and you should also keep in mind that by default all Spring beans are singletons.